# What's the diffrence between pandas pd.to_pickle and pickle module pickle.dump, when saving DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

I would like to save python pandas `DataFrame` object as pickle. What's the diffrence in using `pandas.to_pickle` vs `pickle.dumps`?

I've made some tests. Here's my test code :

```py
import pandas as pd
import pickle
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'), index=['x', 'y'])

# Save
df.to_pickle('df1.pickle')
with open('df2.pickle','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(df, f)

# Load
df1 = pd.read_pickle('df1.pickle')
with open('df2.pickle','rb') as f:
    df2 = pickle.load(f)

# Is ok?
if (df1 == df2).all().all():
    print('Data is ok.')

# Load opposite
df3 = pd.read_pickle('df2.pickle')
with open('df1.pickle','rb') as f:
    df4 = pickle.load(f)

# Is ok?
if (df3 == df4).all().all():
    print('Data opposite is ok.')
```

Result :

```py
Data is ok.
Data opposite is ok.
```

Is there any diffrence? I see some diffrence in output pickle file size. Pandas version file is bigger.

```bash
-rw-rw-r-- 1 spasz spasz 694 lis 15 17:38 df1.pickle
-rw-rw-r-- 1 spasz spasz 662 lis 15 17:38 df2.pickle
```

Tested on python 3.8.0, pandas 1.5.0.

Comment: Except for some wrapping for house keeping, not much. `pd.to_pickle` pretty much calls `pickle.dump` (or `.dumps`) [directly](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/91111fd99898d9dcaa6bf6bedb662db4108da6e6/pandas/io/pickle.py#L104-L112).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing module code for `pickle` (python3.8) and `pandas` 1.5.0 here are my thoughts.

## Saving/dumping DataFrame to pickle

Pickle code :

- Default using pickle protocol `DEFAULT_PROTOCOL` if not specified. `DEFAULT_PROTOCOL`(==4) is not the `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`(==5).

Pandas code :

- Default using pickle protocol `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`,
- Handles error GH#39002 when saving pickle with protocol==5 and compression bz2 or xz,

## Reading DataFrame from pickle

Pickle code :

- No important diffrence to mention,

Pandas code :

- Default use of direct call to `pickle.load()`
- Catches some exceptions to handle data written in previous `pandas` versions  and `python 2.7` unicode errors (see GH#28645 and GH#31988)

## My final thoughts

As @DeepSpace said, pandas pretty much calls `pickle` functions directly. If you're creating new data with current `pandas` versions, and not using pickle protocol==5 with bz2/xz compression, then you can safely use of pickle module functions.