# Is it safe to save Dataframe wrapped with other object as pickle?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

I would like to save `Dataframe` as pickle together with some other data. I could use a dict wrapper for it or specialized class. Is it safe to to save/load these `DataFrame` using module `pickle` dump/load functions or should I always save `Dataframe` with pandas `to_pickle/read_pickle` methods? What do i lose, when i save/load without pandas code?

Example what i would like to do (using dict to wrap all data) :

```py
import pandas as pd
import pickle
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'), index=['x', 'y'])
dictDf = {'Important data' : False, 'Other information' : 'Important', 'Df' : df}

# Save
with open('dictDf.pickle','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(dictDf, f)

with open('dictDf.pickle','rb') as f:
    dictDfReaded = pickle.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

In other question ([What's the diffrence between pandas pd.to_pickle and pickle module pickle.dump, when saving DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74449223/2516697)) there is answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/74458675/2516697) about diffrences between  module `pandas` pickle functions and  module `pickle` functions.

So generally speaking, except from some specific cases(python2.7, protocol==5 and bz2/xz compresssion), it's safe to save/load `DataFrame` packed inside other object as `pickle` with module `pickle` functions.

Comment: Yes, this is something I am using frequently. As it is explained in the answer there are several versions that might cause an issue. So if your python and library versions allow that you can do it